# visual studio intellisense add help

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using [Npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/) to connect to the postgresql database from visual studio 2010. With the download package there is an XML file named Npgsql which seems to contain some information which we generally see in the visual studio intellisense. Now I want to add this intellisense information into the IDE so that it is available while coding.

Can I do that with this XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it alongside the DLL that you reference, and it should be picked up automatically.

VS looks for an XML file in the same directory with the same name but an "xml" extension instead of "dll" or "exe".